# How to create an instance of any type (id) in Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, introspection, objective-c-runtime

I've an NSArray instance containing some objects of some type (NSDictionary)..

I need to copy this Array into an NSArray of some runtime-known type.

So I need to create instances of the runtime-known type and copy the contents of the NSDictionary into.

I've actually created these instances of type NSObject, but when querying it after-head, I got `unrecognized selector` error!

```
NSUInteger count = [value count];
NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:count];

if (count > 0)
{
    for (int i=0; i < [value count]; i++)
    {
        id newObj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
        id currentValue = [value objectAtIndex:i];
        [self objectFromDictionary:currentValue object:newObj];
        [arr addObject:newObj];
    }
}

[arr release];
```

EDIT:
`objectFromDictionary` forget about it, what it do is to inspect the properties of `newObj` and set it by the values from the dictionary. it is doing its work good.

`EDIT 2:`

Please see why I am trying to do this:

[Type of objects inside non-parameterized arrays in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560989/how-to-know-the-typed-of-objects-inside-non-parameterized-arrays-the-json-parsin)

Comment: What exactly is your `objectFromDictionary:object:` supposed to do, you should post the code for that because allocating an NSObject is generally pointless.

Comment: Isn't this what NSCopying copyWithZone is for?  So long as the object you want to copy implements copyWithZone it should work.  If the object doesn't implement copyWithZone you're screwed.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
id newObj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

to:

```
id newObj = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

or:

```
id newObj = [[NSClassFromString(@"NSMutableArray") alloc] init];
```

or, if you want to derive the class from an existing object:

```
id newObj = [[[existingObj class] alloc] init];
```

Comment: It is not of `NSMutableArray`, it is of some unknown type until runtime

Comment: Then use the other option I listed.

Comment: What option? the NSClassFromString? Idont have the type until I find some way to inspect it at runtime

Comment: What do you mean by "inspect it at runtime"? If you already have an object of the correct class, you can do `[[[obj class] alloc] init]`.

Comment: Here's the problem.... I don't know the type of the objects that should stored in the new array!, thankfully, please re-read my question.

Comment: Muhammad, currently the question does not make since, please specify how you know the type at runtime and how you are trying to use it, Ole Begemann already provided sufficient examples to implement runtime class allocation. If these do not work for what you are trying to do then you might be taking the incorrect approach to your problem.

Comment: Please see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560989/how-to-know-the-typed-of-objects-inside-non-parameterized-arrays-the-json-parsin

Comment: Do you have a sample of the JSON you're attempting to decode?  I think if you had that, and could explain what the object graph it should convert to looks like, you'll get better answers.