# Type of objects inside non-parameterized arrays in JSON

Tags: java, objective-c, json, generics, gson

I am trying to write simple function that converts Json strings into Objects.

The language I am using is objective-c however this question discusses issues doesn't relate to this lang.

**My question is, How to know the Type of Objects that laid inside a json array that is to be mapped into non-parameterized (a.k.a non-generic) lists??**

I found two Json Java libraries unable to solve this issue, **Jakson** and **Gson** and here's the example:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Gson g = new Gson();
        Office o =  g.fromJson(
                "{\"empx\":\"1\",\"emps\":[{\"firstName\":\"Muhammad\",\"lastName\":\"Abdullah\"},{\"firstName\":\"XX\",\"lastName\":null}]}"
                , Office.class);
        System.out.println(((Employee)o.getEmps().get(0)).getFirstName());
    }
}

class Office
{
    private List emps;
    private String empx;

    public String getEmpx()
    {
        return empx;
    }
    public void setEmpx(String empx)
    {
        this.empx = empx;
    }

    public List getEmps()
    {
        return emps;
    }

    public void setEmps(List emps)
    {
        this.emps = emps;
    }
}


class Employee implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

In `Google Gson` they considered this array's objects as objects of type `java.lang.Object`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object
```

But Jaskon was much smarter, it considered this `unknown` object to be a Map:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

However, Both have been failed to detect the Object (which I think is impossible!)

**So, In a language that doesn't support Parameterized types (Generics), Is n't any way to accomplish this?**

Comment: Of course there is no way for it to detect that you want it to create an `Employee` object: there is no reference to `Employee` whatsoever! And it’s unclear what you’re actually asking here.

Comment: Wrt Gson, Jackson, it is not impossible to detect the type, but that requires either inclusion of type information (polymorphic (de)serailziation), or specifying type with your call. Both can do latter, Jackson at least can do former.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using dictionaries.  The key keys could infer the types or there could be a type key.